# NoMethodError in my Teams#Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial-views, nomethoderror

For some reason I get an error on this line. Everything seems to be correct.

```
undefined method `datetime' for #<Game:0x87e73f0>
```

Screenshot of console log:
www.gyazo.com/0947c493218a3fecdb5849e1e13f181a

app/views/games/_form.html.erb where line #4 raised

```
<%= f.text_field :datetime %>
```

Migration file:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :datetime
      t.string :location
      t.references :team, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Partial Form:

```
<%= form_for([@team, @team.games.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :datetime %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :datetime %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :location %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :location %>
    </p>

    <br>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :teams do
    resources :members
  end

  resources :teams do
    resources :games
  end

  root "teams#index"
end
```

Comment: no method what? put the full error

Comment: Show us the server log where you see the error.. It will help us to help you

Comment: Sorry about that. It was: 
undefined method `datetime' for #<Game:0x87e73f0>

https://gyazo.com/0947c493218a3fecdb5849e1e13f181a

Comment: did you do `rake db:migrate` after creating the migration ?

Comment: open your rails console, and type `Game.column_names`. Show the output here

Comment: open rails c type `Game.first` and paste the result.

Comment: @ArupRakshit for Game.column_names I got:
=> ["id", "date_time", "location", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]

Comment: @matanco For Game.first I got:
SELECT "game".* FROM "games" ORDER BY "games". "id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil

Comment: So you have to use `date_time` not `datetime` . Not sure, how your migration given name changed while the actual table got created. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't like the idea that you've called a column "datetime" - if it's not protected, it's definitely misleading (considering most SQL flavours have a `datetime` column type).

Apart from it appearing that you're calling the wrong column name:

```
Game.column_names I got: => ["id", "date_time", "location", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

You need to reference `date_time`:

```
 <%= f.label :date_time %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :date_time %>
```

... you'd be much better changing the name of the attribute in the database:

```
$ rails g migration ChangeDateTime

#db/migrate/change_date_time____.rb
class ChangeDateTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     rename_column :games, :date_time, :start_time
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will allow you to reference `start_time`, and should not conflict with your SQL installation in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the column name Change datetime to date_time:

```
<%= form_for([@team, @team.games.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :date_time %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :date_time %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :location %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :location %>
    </p>

    <br>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: why are you suggesting to change the field name? any specific reason?

Comment: read the comments: here is the output of column names: "id", "date_time", "location", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at"] so he have typo!

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I forgot what I named it before.

Comment: did you manually type your migration file in this question @user3808788?? how is it `datetime`?

Comment: @matanco Just for future reference, do you know how I could change the name of the column in the database?